# Linux: get the location of logfiles

Tags: python, linux, logging, environment-variables

I would like to have my (python) script (located anywhere) write a logfile
and place that logfile in an appropriate location. In Linux:Debian this could be /var/log.

I was wondering if such a logfile location could be retrieved from the system? Is there an environment variable or something?

Comment: The second paragraph of your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by retrieved from the system? As in, will your code run only on Linux or even on Windows?

Comment: It runs on the same linux machine where the log should be placed.

Comment: Linux always comes with the /var/log directory. It's not unique to Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to log on Linux/UNIX is to use the system logger. From your application (or daemon) you call the `syslog` system function (see manpage).

This function will forward your log to the system logger. From there, the system logger will take care of writing these log messages to a file. You can also then customize the behavior of the system logger to write some of your messages to a special file, or to ignore them.

For a direct answer to your question, `/var/log/` is defined by the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) as the location where log files must be written to. No need to rely on an environment variable.

Comment: I'm relatively new to the internal mechanics of linux and appreciate your pointing at the syslog function. THX